# Determine the size of an InputStream

Tags: java, arrays, size, inputstream

My current situation is: I have to read a file and put the contents into `InputStream`. Afterwards I need to place the contents of the `InputStream` into a byte array which requires (as far as I know) the size of the `InputStream`. Any ideas?

As requested, I will show the input stream that I am creating from an uploaded file

```
InputStream uploadedStream = null;
FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
java.util.List items = upload.parseRequest(request);      
java.util.Iterator iter = items.iterator();

while (iter.hasNext()) {
    FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();
    if (!item.isFormField()) {
        uploadedStream = item.getInputStream();
        //CHANGE uploadedStreambyte = item.get()
    }
}
```

The request is a `HttpServletRequest` object, which is like the `FileItemFactory` and `ServletFileUpload` is from the Apache Commons FileUpload package.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just wanted to add, Apache Commons IO has stream support utilities to perform the copy. (Btw, what do you mean by placing the file into an inputstream? Can you show us your code?)

**Edit:**

Okay, what do you want to do with the contents of the item?
There is an `item.get()` [which returns](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem.html#get()) the entire thing in a byte array.

**Edit2**

`item.getSize()` will return the uploaded [file size](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem.html#getSize()).

Comment: I currently save the file to a blob field in the database and i send it as a binarystream (input as a inputstream), now i require the inputstream in a byte array since i need to make a signature of data and the function only takes byte arrays.

Comment: item.get() nets you the byte array, as I mentioned. And don't worry about performance an size unless you are working with several MB images.

Comment: That could be the case since the image is uploaded by a user, and i can't seem to find a way to auto trim images on the server side. :(

Comment: What do you mean by auto trim images? get() will give you the entire uploaded file(image) as byte[]. Then you go ahead and use it on any OutputStream.write(), wrap it to ByteArrayInputStream again, etc.

Comment: I changed the solution to this post since its answer was more fine tuned for my current setup

Answer (score 88):

This is a REALLY old thread, but it was still the first thing to pop up when I googled the issue.  So I just wanted to add this:

```
InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
int length = inputStream.available();
```

Worked for me.  And MUCH simpler than the other answers here.

**Warning** This solution does not provide reliable results regarding the total size of a stream. Except from the JavaDoc:

> Note that while some implementations of {@code InputStream} will return
>        * the total number of bytes in the stream, many will not.

Comment: I don't think that's accurate.  From the Javadocs:  "Note that while some implementations of InputStream will return the total number of bytes in the stream, many will not. It is never correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer intended to hold all data in this stream."  So it may have worked on your VM, but might not work on someone else's.   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available()

Comment: Oh psych. Nice catch!  I guess this trick is not good for code that needs to be portable.  I was using for a school project, so it worked for me.  Thanks though, good to know for the future!

Comment: That is perfect when you have all the data in memory like in a ByteArrayInputStream.

Comment: It is WRONG! As the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available())  said about the `available()` method "Note that while some implementations of InputStream will return the total number of bytes in the stream, many will not. It is never correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer intended to hold all data in this stream."

Comment: is.avaliable returns 0 if eof is reached otherwise it always returns 1

Comment: The answer is misleading, What about [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/java/io/InputStream.html#available()), there is clearly stated: "Note that **this method provides such a weak guarantee** that **it is not very useful in practice**".

Comment: From the docs: "you must not use this method to size a container and assume that you can read the entirety of the stream without needing to resize the container"

Comment: In my case it works well on one VM but fails with an exception on another. The exception is "InputStream has already been read - do not use InputStreamResource if a stream needs to be read multiple times". It happens because after calling `available()` I send it as the body for HTTP request to `ResponseEntity` object.

Comment: This is incorrect at so many levels...
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available()

Comment: so your solution works... except it doesnt? nice

Comment: how the heck did this stupid answer gain so many upvotes?

Comment: Please don't use it, you might feel it works while testing, but will give you nightmares for files exceeding int range for sure.

Answer (score 46):

I would read into a [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) and then call [toByteArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#toByteArray--) to get the resultant byte array. You don't need to define the size in advance (although it's possibly an optimisation *if you know it*. In many cases you won't)

Comment: I seem to have found that inputstream have a toString() method and then i can just call a getBytes() to create a byte array off of the string. I'm wondering if there are any performance issues from doing this?

Comment: You need to be careful with bytes/character conversions. Is this originally a byte stream ? If it contains characters, how are they encoded etc. If you're getting these via a network connection, I would suspect that's your main performance bottleneck and I wouldn't worry about conversion overhead

Comment: I currently read the inputstream with the image into a database as a binarystream, this seems to work well as i can read the file back out afterwords and its still an image

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone, unless there is any reason not to go with a convert stream to string using .toString() and then to byte array using .getBytes(), i will continue with this solution.

Comment: I wopuld have thought it's easier to read in a loop from your inputstream to the byte array output stream, and then get the byte array, thus avoiding char encodings. But if you're happy that toString() works...

Comment: Yes, there is. String.getBytes() will have conversion issues.

Comment: Alright so if String.getBytes really has a type conversion issue will the following changes to my code work (shown in initial post with //CHANGE)

Comment: Yes. You get the full raw byte array, no conversion, no issues.

Comment: Isn't this really memory inefficient if all you want is the size?

Answer (score 25):

You can't determine the amount of data in a stream without reading it; you can, however, ask for the size of a file:

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length()

If that isn't possible, you can write the bytes you read from the input stream to a [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) which will grow as required.

Comment: In my scenario the inputstream contains an uploaded file from a HTML form, i can't get the file size since i'm not loading the file off the hard drive.

Comment: If your input stream has mark() support, you could mark at the beginning and just read through it entirely - then reset() and start processing it.

Comment: the file is an image (potentially large) so reading through the stream twice would cause performance issues wouldn't it?

Comment: Try it. If it’s very slow you have performance issues. Otherwise, you don’t. It’s that simple.

Comment: @ChronoXIII: True. This is why I asked for a small code sample so we could see your scenario. If your image is already in memory (thanks to fileupload or something) then it opens more options.

Answer (score 9):

For InputStream

```
org.apache.commons.io.IoUtils.toByteArray(inputStream).length()
```

For Optional < MultipartFile >

```
Stream.of(multipartFile.get()).mapToLong(file->file.getSize()).findFirst().getAsLong()
```

Comment: I cannot find IoUtils anywhere. I guess you mean org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils,

Comment: IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream).length didn't work for me.

Comment: Yes. It is not working with IOUtils. Not sure why is this method and how this can be useful.

Comment: It's a byte array returned which has length () method. I just forgot to add the paranthesis

Comment: Can't we just do inputStream.readAllBytes().length?

Answer (score 6):

The function below should work with any `InputStream`. As other answers have hinted, you can't reliably find the length of an `InputStream` without reading through it, but unlike other answers, you *should not* attempt to hold the entire stream in memory by reading into a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, nor is there any reason to. Instead of reading the stream, you should ideally rely on other API for stream sizes, for example getting the size of a file using the `File` API.

```
public static int length(InputStream inputStream, int chunkSize) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
    int chunkBytesRead = 0;
    int length = 0;
    while((chunkBytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        length += chunkBytesRead;
    }
    return length;
}
```

Choose a reasonable value for `chunkSize` appropriate to the kind of `InputStream`. E.g. reading from disk it would not be efficient to have too small a value for `chunkSize`.

Comment: I agree with @Samuel, this is the correct way to get file length from InputStream.

Answer (score 4):

you can get the size of InputStream using getBytes(inputStream) of Utils.java check this following link

[Get Bytes from Inputstream](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180__File/GetbytesfromInputStream.htm)

Comment: Shouldn't this also be a correct answer? Any problems with this solution?

Comment: If you were planning to use your input stream it will have already been read.

Answer (score 2):

When explicitly dealing with a `ByteArrayInputStream` then contrary to some of the comments on this page you can use the `.available()` function to get the size. Just have to do it before you start reading from it.

From the JavaDocs:

> Returns the number of remaining bytes that can be read (or skipped
>   over) from this input stream. The value returned is count - pos, which
>   is the number of bytes remaining to be read from the input buffer.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html#available()

Answer (score 2):

If you know that your `InputStream` is a `FileInputStream` or a `ByteArrayInputStream`, you can use a little reflection to get at the stream size **without reading the entire contents**. Here's an example method:

```java
static long getInputLength(InputStream inputStream) {
    try {
        if (inputStream instanceof FilterInputStream) {
            FilterInputStream filtered = (FilterInputStream)inputStream;
            Field field = FilterInputStream.class.getDeclaredField("in");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            InputStream internal = (InputStream) field.get(filtered);
            return getInputLength(internal);
        } else if (inputStream instanceof ByteArrayInputStream) {
            ByteArrayInputStream wrapper = (ByteArrayInputStream)inputStream;
            Field field = ByteArrayInputStream.class.getDeclaredField("buf");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            byte[] buffer = (byte[])field.get(wrapper);
            return buffer.length;
        } else if (inputStream instanceof FileInputStream) {
            FileInputStream fileStream = (FileInputStream)inputStream;
            return fileStream.getChannel().size();
        }
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException | IOException exception) {
        // Ignore all errors and just return -1.
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This could be extended to support additional input streams, I am sure.

Comment: If you can afford re-creation of the inputStream and the wait for it, you could read it all to get its size as a fallback to all of these

Comment: Like this approach, as it uses available info and avoids actually reading the stream. One might add a recursion for the nested InputStream of BufferedInputStream, which then covers most use cases, where the length is known a priori.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to stream the data to another object that doesn't allow you to directly determine the size (e.g. `javax.imageio.ImageIO`), then you can wrap your `InputStream` within a [`CountingInputStream`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/input/CountingInputStream.html) (Apache Commons IO), and then read the size:

```
CountingInputStream countingInputStream = new CountingInputStream(inputStream);
// ... process the whole stream ...
int size = countingInputStream.getCount();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to your pom.xml:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
  </dependency>
```

Use to get the content type lenght (InputStream file):

```
IOUtils.toByteArray(file).length
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this method, you just have to pass the InputStream

```
public String readIt(InputStream is) {
    if (is != null) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"), 8);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        is.close();
        return sb.toString();
    }
    return "error: ";
}
```

Comment: -1, this assumes the `InputStream` is always a String (not necessary because it may be binary data), and in any case it doesn't return the size of the stream which is what the question asked for. Moreover it adds extra bytes (`\n`) to the data so `sb.length()` will also be inaccurate.

Comment: Ok, i understand, so this is useful when you know you are expecting to receive a `String` stream. `\n` is really needed because you have to give some format to the input received, I don't want a chorizo long `String`, so even those `\n`counts.

Answer (score -2):

```
    try {
        InputStream connInputStream = connection.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int size = connInputStream.available();
```

int available ()
Returns an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this input stream without blocking by the next invocation of a method for this input stream. The next invocation might be the same thread or another thread. A single read or skip of this many bytes will not block, but may read or skip fewer bytes.

[InputStream - Android SDK | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html#available())

Comment: This an error, such i found that available() function return just the active data size and no the hole stream length.