# Cannot get an image from inputStream

Tags: image, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, inputstream

First thing, I'm new in jee and rest services, I'm developing an application in java that receive an image from a client and stores it in a glassfish db. Then it can be returned. I´m having a problem gettin the image from the input stream, I tried ImageIO.read(inputStream) like seeing in many questions here, but it´s allways return null. And if I convert it to bytes, save it, recoverted to image file from the bytes the image its shown corrupted. Aparently im saving rubish with the image when i convert that way the inputStream.

How can I extract the image correctly from the inputStream? There is another way to send it?

[image: I´m posting the image in this way]

Code from the app side:

```
     BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imagen);

     @POST
     @Path("subir/{usuario}/{nombreImagen}")
     public Response obtenerImagen(@PathParam("usuario") String usuario,
                                   @PathParam("nombreImagen") String nombreImagen,
                                   InputStream imagen) throws IOException {
         BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imagen);
         ...
```

Comment: I recently did a project transforming images and used img = ImageIO.read(new File(f)) with no problem, but I wrapped it in a try-catch block just in case, so I could tell if there was an IOException while reading it. You might also try reading the image from a standalone program and see if that works - call it a unit test if needed to justify it.

Comment: That form looks like it would post multi-part data. Maybe some clues [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157677/java-rest-correct-parameters-for-jquery-multipart-form-data-file-upload).