# Socket InputStream.read(byte[],int,int) always return the third parameter value

Tags: java, sockets, networking, socket.io

I use Java 8 write a simple client and server to verify use `Zero copy` is more efficient than traditional approach from the [article](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/j-zerocopy/). But I encountered one problem，in the server side the method `InputStream.reamd(byte[],int postion,int length)` always return the `length` even the last read from InputStream has no enougth data.

code like this；

```
    while (true) {
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

        byte[] readBuf = new byte[4096];
        long sum = 0L;
        while (true) {
            int readN = inputStream.read(readBuf, 0, 4096);
            System.out.println("read from buffer " + readN);
            if (-1 == readN) {
                break;
            }
            sum += readN;
        }
        System.out.println("total receive " + sum + " bytes");
    }
```

The last two output is:

```
read from buffer 4096
read from buffer -1
```

The except output is:

```
read from buffer 3440
read from buffer -1
```

The document of Java say:

> public int read(byte[] b,
>                   int off,
>                   int len)
>            throws IOException
>
> Reads up to len bytes of data from the input stream into an array of bytes. An attempt is made to read as many as len bytes, but a smaller number may be read. The number of bytes actually read is returned as an integer.

Why the behavior of code not consistent with the document?

Comment: Consider the last read ，the `InputStream`` only has 3440 bytes data，i think the read` should be only read 3440 bytes data from `InputStream` and return 3440 not 4096.

Comment: now i am confused about as the expected as the real output: why (when consistent with documentation), it (the 1. print statement) should ever return something out of the range [-1, ... , 2048] ??

Comment: oh the code i copy is wrong,the buffer size is 4096.client total send 158313840 byte,`158313840 % 4096 == 3440`,so the last expected size is 3440

Comment: you don't add (`sum += readN;`) the last chunk, because you get a `-1` and `break;` in the last loop iteration. (So, your sum *will always be* `% buffLen == 0`) ...and I'am also not sure how to get the "size of an inputstream" ..except buffering it to end....and count. :)

Comment: some answers/links from here will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1119332/592355, i especially like the `InputStream.available()` :))

Comment: @xerx593 Thank you very much,I debug the code and the print the size of OutputStream(client side) and InputStream(server side),the size of them is same（158314496 btes）but the file client send is 158313840 bytes,so I may have missed something.Thanks again！！