# How measure download speed with OkHTTP?

Tags: android, okhttp

I am downloading the file using `OkHttp3`, I want to see the downloading speed. but I am confused about how to measure the speed.

I tried getting the current millis before reading the buffer and calculating after it is written, but it always returns a static value.

Following is my download function.

```
fun download(fileName: String) {
    val request = Request.Builder().url(url)
        .get().build()
    val call = OkHttpClient().newCall(request)
    val response = call.execute()

    if (response.isSuccessful) {
        var inputStream: InputStream? = null

        try {
            inputStream = response.body()?.byteStream()
            val buffer = ByteArray(8192)
            val mediaFile = File(downloadDir, fileName)
            val output = RandomAccessFile(mediaFile, "rw")
            output.seek(0)

            while (true) {
                val readed = inputStream?.read(buffer)

                if (readed == -1 || readed == null) {
                    break
                }

                output.write(buffer, 0, readed)
                downloaded.append(readed.toLong())
            }
            output.close()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            // TODO: handle IOException
            console.log("${e.message}")
        } finally {
            inputStream?.close()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119332/determine-the-size-of-an-inputstream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a very simple problem, I got confused by overthinking. Anyway here is the solution.

all I need to do is store the downloaded bytes in a variable after `1s` subtract downloaded bytes from newly downloaded bytes, that will give me the downloaded bytes in `1s`, then I can use those bytes to convert into speed like `kbps` or `Mbps`.

```
fun getSpeed(callback: (String) -> Unit) {
    doAsync {
        var prevDownloaded = 0L
        while (true) {
            if (contentLength != null) {
                if (downloaded.get() >= contentLength!!) {
                    break
                }
            }

            if (prevDownloaded != 0L) {
                callback(formatBytes(downloaded.get() - prevDownloaded))
            }
            prevDownloaded = downloaded.get()
            Thread.sleep(1000)
        }
    }
}
```